# Adjusting Modal Terms and Conditions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Good day, just asking how can I center the text in my terms and conditions on a modal pop up. adding modal css to try and center it does not seem to work. thanks for anyone who can help.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id = "myModal" tabindex = "-1" role = "dialog" aria-labelledby = "myModalLabel" aria-hidden = "true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="container spacer text-align-justify">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 spacer"><br><br></div> <!--spacer-->

              <div class="col-md-12" style="width: 700px;">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-align-center">
                  <h2 class="bold_font">GENERAL TERMS AND CONDITIONS</h2>
                  <br><br><br><br>
                </div>..................................................
```

...................................TERMS AND CONDITIONS CONTENT

CSS:

```
.modal {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   margin-left: -150px;
   margin-top: -150px;
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsRJ0.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add transform: `translate(-50%, -50%); with left: 50%; top:50%;` in modal box class

```
.modal {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        top:50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css,

```
.modal {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        margin-top: 100px; #add according to your requirement
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding: 10px; # add if you want
       }
```